# Change startup order c#

Tags: windows, startup, autorun

How do I change the startup list? Basically I have a program that is a computer locking system and when I enter it into the registry to start up when login, it is like the last thing to open.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775073/

Comment: no its not, that is to start up the application before windows login, this is to change when my program starts up after login.

I need to change when my program starts up, for example windows msn starts up before my program, and I need to program to start up as soon as the user logs in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which startup list are you using to launch your application?

There are actually quite a few startup lists (see below). The order of application launch within a given list is *not* configurable (e.g. there is no way to choose which application in the *Startup Folder* launch first) but, the order in which the startup lists are iterated is fixed (e.g. Applications in the *Common Startup Folder* will always launch first, before applications in the *Startup Folder*).

It sounds like you want to launch your application on user login, so listing your application path in the *All Users-Run* registry key should ensure that it launches fairly soon after logon.

Add a string (REG_SZ) value to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key with the path to your application as the data.

(Aside: Background reading on the [arcane terminology of the Windows registry](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/04/9394113.aspx))

**STARTUP ORDER FOR WINDOWS 9X/ME**

1. config.sys
2. autoexec.bat
3. wininit.ini
4. winstart.bat
5. system.ini
6. win.ini
7. All Users-RunOnce (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce`)
8. All Users-RunServices
   (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices`)
9. All Users-RunOnce
   (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`)
10. All Users-Run
    (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`)
11. All Users-RunOnceEx
    (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx`)
12. All Users-RunEx
    (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunEx`)
13. Current User-RunOnce
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`)
14. Current User-Run
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`)
15. Current User-RunOnceEx
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx`)
16. Current User-RunEx
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunEx`)
17. Common Startup Folder
18. Startup Folder

**STARTUP ORDER FOR WINDOWS NT4/2000/XP**

1. BootExecute
   (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute
2. Services
3. User enters a password and logon to the system
4. UserInit
   (`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\UserInit`)
5. Shell
   (`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`)
6. All Users-RunOnce
   (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`)
7. All Users-Run
   (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`)
8. All Users-RunOnceEx
   (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx`)
9. All Users-RunEx
   (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunEx`)
10. Current User-RunOnce
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`)
11. Current User-Run
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`)
12. Current User-RunOnceEx
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx`)
13. Current User-RunEx
    (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunEx`)
14. Common Startup Folder
15. Startup Folder

(*[Source](http://www.greatis.com/security/startuporder.htm)*)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I currently have the application starting up with the registry entry, but my application takes ages before it will start up, is there any way in which I can make it one of the first applications starting up?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. If you are trying to create something that is truly secure you might need to take a fundamentally different approach. (For example, there may be a way to suppress these AutoRun applications and therefore prevent your app from launching at all.)

Comment: Hmm alright then thanks, you know of any guides that can help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Not offhand, sorry. The only things I know about in this area are GINA and logon scripts.